# Starting tomcat v7.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem

Tags: java, tomcat, servidor

Estou tentando dar start do Servidor Tomcat localmente, mas ocorre esse problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você já conseguiu rodar ele alguma vez? Ou é a primeira vez que tenta e já dá erro?

Comment: Ontem estava funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Poste o **boot.log** num paste bin da vida pra gente ver.

Comment: fail... O Erro estava no meu servlet OlaMundo que tinha o mesmo @WebServlet("/oi") do servlet adicionarContato. Obrigado de qualquer forma. Sou novo em java para WEB

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre não era um erro de verdade.